# Can we touch the original object reference after transfer it to another program via Interprocess Communication?

Tags: android, ipc

The case is:
In **server**, I have an object **A**, then transfer it to another program in **client** via Interprocess Communication (e.g. AIDL).

By AIDL, the object A in **server** will be decomposed --> transferred --> and recovered in the client. Let's say it is recovered as object **A'** in program in the **client**.

My question is:
Is there something connect with object **A** and **A'** ?
In other words, after transferring the object **A** to another program via IPC, can we obtain the reference of original object **A** in the program in the **client** ?

Comment: A and A' are different objects in different processes. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to understand why we can call the function in A by A' ?  what's the relationship between this two objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something connect with object A and A' ?

No, for most data types. A and A' are purely independent — pass-by-value, effectively.

The exception is if the type of A is something that is itself defined via AIDL, such as a callback. Then, if the app with A' calls methods on it, those methods are actually invoked on A.

> after transferring the object A to another program via IPC, can we obtain the reference of original object A in the program in the client ?

That is not possible, as A and A' belong to separate processes.

Comment: So, we can call method of object A in client is not because we can get the original object's reference, right? Then, how we can do that?

Comment: @tiger: It works the same way as how the client talked to the service in the first place: AIDL-defined IPC. See [this pair of sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/Callback) for an example of a client passing a callback object to a service, which then calls methods on its proxy to that callback object.